# how do you divide each value from a pandas series in sequence

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I was trying to figure out how to divide values from a DataFrame. But here I made an example for pandas series

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 16,64,128,360,720])
a
-----------------
0     1
1     2
2     16
3     64
4    128
5    360
6    720
```

So is there any way I could divide a number in a given row by the value from the previous row?

```
0     2
1     8
2     4
3     2
4     2.8
5     2
```

Furthermore, I also tried to get the output like "if the value is double, print the index".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are you doing to get from your original df to your expected output? Please edit your question

Comment: Your example `pd.Series` is different from your included input data.

Comment: That's a very ill posed question. The data in the first code snipped is not correct with the output plus there is no description of the division he wants to do and no imports

Comment: @shenghong zhong Now you modified the question properly. Now spend time awarding the ones who answered you and solved the problem, don't leave it without accepted answer as the other questions you have

Comment: @DaSim Tx, I just learned how to accept answers by clicking the tick. Everyday is a school day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it seems to me is that you are trying to divide a number in a given row by the one of the previous. This can be achieved using this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 16,64,128,360,720])
division = pd.Series(np.divide(a.values[1:],a.values[:-1]))
index = pd.Series(np.multiply(division == 2, [i for i in range(len(a)-1)]))
```

Note: your question is very ill posed. You didn't specify what you wanted to achieve, I figured out by myself from the example. You also added a wrong snipped of code. Pay attention to make a nicer question next time

Comment: Thank you for taking time. This answered my question. I was trying to write codes to see when the number of user signup doubled over years. I still tried to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what exactly you want to divide your pandas Series by, but you can do it like this :

```
# If you want to store a new result
b = a / value_to_divive_by
# or if you want to apply it directly to your serie
a /= value_to_divive_by
```

or using list comprehension

```
b = [int(nb / your_value_here) for nb in a]
# with a min value to do the divison
b = [int(nb / your_value_here) for nb in a if nb > min_value]
```

There is probably other ways to do what you want, but there is two easy solutions